# Update form fields with dynamic field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts

I need help making it so that when a user edits the values typed in one box, it updates the values in another box.  For example,  when the user updates the fields in **red**, I would like the fields in **orange** to automatically update to reflect the values of the fields in **red**. I have included a screenshot to demonstrate as well as the code I am using.  I thought about using just some javascript ontab but I didn't see any examples with dynamic field names like mine. In the code the fields

```
'<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].start_month"%>' , '<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].start_day"%>' and '<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].start_year"%>'` should update `'<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_month"%>' , '<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_day"%>' and '<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_year"%>'` respectively.
```

[image: input boxes]

Code:

```
<%!
    private String current(int index) {
        String output = "";
        if (index == 0) {
            output = "<td>&nbsp;<font color=\"red\"><em>Current</em></font></td>";
        } else if (index == 1) {
            output = "<td>&nbsp;<font color=\"blue\"><em>Next Most Recent</em></font></td>";
        } else if (index == 2) {
            output = "<td>&nbsp;<font color=\"blue\"><em>2nd Most Recent</em></font></td>";
        } else if (index == 3) {
            output = "<td>&nbsp;<font color=\"blue\"><em>3rd Most Recent</em></font></td>";
        } else if (index >= 4) {
            output = "<td>&nbsp;<font color=\"blue\"><em>" + index + "th Most Recent</em></font></td>";
        }
        return output;
    }
%>
<html:form action="EditUnit.do" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" focus="xid">
    <p><bean:define id="oldForm" property="writeUnitForm" name="ses" scope="session"/>
    <bean:define id="newForm" name="EditUnitForm" scope="session"/>
    <bean:define id="unit_id" property="unit_id" name="oldForm" scope="page"/>
    <bean:define id="unit" property='<%= (String) pageContext.getAttribute("unit_id")%>' name="listUnitInfo" scope="page"/>
    Unit ID: <bean:write property="unit_num" name="unit" scope="page"/></p>
<hr/>
Unit names: Enter Names and start date (default: today)
<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="border-bottom: #000000 1px solid;">
        <th>Start (mm/dd/yyyy)&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;End (mm/dd/yyyy)&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Long Name</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <%! int longNameIndex;%>
    <%! int longNameCount = 0;%>
    <logic:iterate id="lnEntryItem" indexId="longNameIndex" property="long_names" name="newForm" scope="page">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><html:text property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].start_month"%>' size="2" maxlength="2"/>/<html:text property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].start_day"%>' size="2" maxlength="2"/>/<html:text property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].start_year"%>' size="4" maxlength="4"/>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</td>
        <% if (longNameIndex == 0) {%>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><html:text property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_month"%>' size="2" maxlength="2"/>/<html:text property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_day"%>' size="2" maxlength="2"/>/<html:text property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_year"%>' size="4" maxlength="4"/>&nbsp;</td>
        <% } else {%>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><html:text readonly="true" property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_month"%>' size="2" maxlength="2"/>/<html:text readonly="true" property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_day"%>' size="2" maxlength="2"/>/<html:text readonly="true" property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].end_year"%>' size="4" maxlength="4"/>&nbsp;</td>
        <% }%>
        <td>&nbsp;<html:text property='<%="lnEntryItem[" + longNameIndex + "].data"%>' size="70" maxlength="70"/>&nbsp;</td>
        <%=current(longNameIndex)%>
        <% if (longNameIndex == 0) {%>
        <td><font color="red"><strong>*Required</strong></font></td>
            <% } else {%>
        <td></td>
        <% }%>
        </tr>
        <%longNameCount++;%>
    </logic:iterate>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="btn_addfield_longName" value="Add a Long Name"/>
            <% if (longNameCount > 1) {%>
            &nbsp;<input type="submit" name="btn_rmvfield_longName" value="Remove Last Row"/>
            <% }%>
            <%longNameCount = 0;%>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery script I was attempting to use:

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
$('START DATE ID').keyup(function() { //how to know what that is?
    var item=$(this);
    if(item.val() != "") {
        var tot = item.val();
        $('END DATE ID').val(tot); //how to know what that is?
    }
});
});
    </script>
```

But I am not sure how I can modify that to incorporate the dynamic field names.

Here is the HTML of the jsp:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="border-bottom: #000000 1px solid;">
            <th>Start (mm/dd/yyyy)&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;End (mm/dd/yyyy)&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Long Name</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="lnEntryItem[0].id" value="2750"/>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[0].start_month" maxlength="2" size="2" value="05"/>
                /<input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[0].start_day" maxlength="2" size="2" value="30"/>
                /<input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[0].start_year" maxlength="4" size="4" value="2013"/>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[0].end_month" maxlength="2" size="2" value=""/>
                /<input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[0].end_day" maxlength="2" size="2" value=""/>/
                <input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[0].end_year" maxlength="4" size="4" value=""/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[0].data" maxlength="70" size="70" value="Jen's test unit"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;<font color="red"><em>Current</em></font></td>
            <td><font color="red"><strong>*Required</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="lnEntryItem[1].id" value="2757"/>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[1].start_month" maxlength="2" size="2" value="05"/>
                /<input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[1].start_day" maxlength="2" size="2" value="01"/>
                /<input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[1].start_year" maxlength="4" size="4" value="2013"/>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[1].end_month" maxlength="2" size="2" value="05" readonly="readonly"/>
                /<input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[1].end_day" maxlength="2" size="2" value="30" readonly="readonly"/>
                /<input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[1].end_year" maxlength="4" size="4" value="2013" readonly="readonly"/>
            </td>
            <td>&
                <input type="text" name="lnEntryItem[1].data" maxlength="70" size="70" value="Jen's testing unit"/></td>
            <td><font color="blue"><em>Next Most Recent</em></font></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="btn_addfield_longName" value="Add a Long Name"/>
                <input type="submit" name="btn_rmvfield_longName" value="Remove Last Row"/>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: I have edited the original post with the javascript I was attempting to use. I got it to work for simple field names but I have no idea how to make it work for dynamic field names.

Comment: Ideally you'd be using something semantic, and finding the "next" field of a given class to update and eliminate the need to target specific IDs. But since you have access to the ID of the element that was changed, you can either parse it out, or use a `data-` attribute to set additional info, or so on. I'd **strongly** recommend using a JS library for this, like jQuery or its equivalent: doing this by hand will be a trail of tears.

Comment: How can I write the jquery without knowing what my ID's will be.  There are an unknown amount of lines that the user can have.  I have figured out the jquery script (thanks for the tip), but still have no idea how to point to the correct IDs in the script.  I've updated my original post.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I have updated the original post with the html parse of the jsp code that I posted.

Comment: @Evilsithgirl, I've posted a solution. If you find it useful, don't forget to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Comment: @Evilsithgirl Because the IDs aren't what's important. Once you're in an element's click handler you can search for the next occurence of a specific class: the ID is often irrelevant. It also means you're only searching a small portion of the overall DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your event handlers wrong. Use `keyup` or `change`, not `onkeyup` or `onchange` (which would only be used if you were calling them inline).

Then use the following code:

```
var startDate = $('input[name*="start_"]');

startDate.on('keyup', function () {
    var index = this.name.indexOf('start_'),
        name = this.name.substr(index).replace('start_', 'end_'),
        prevEntry = $(this).parents('tr').next(),
        endDate = prevEntry.find('input[name*="' + name + '"]');
    endDate.val(this.value);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ma8e8/)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, you could try using javascript blur event(s) on the red box to update the orange. The blur event is fired when the red box in this scenario looses focus.

```
document.getElementByID("redboxname1").onblur=function() {
    document.getElementByID("orangebox1").value = document.getElementByID("redbox1").value;
}
```

something like that. If you need a more instant update, try looking at onKeyUp event. Perform similar actions but this would fire directly after the key has been pressed.